# Arrow direction and shape color in smart diagram

Tags: smartdiagram

I want to make following diagram-

[image]
Below is my code of `smartdiagram`-

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true,
        module minimum width=2cm,
        module minimum height=2cm,
        module x sep=3cm,
        text width=2cm,
        additions={
            additional item offset=0.5cm,
            additional item border color=red,
            additional connections disabled=false,
            additional arrow color=red,
            additional arrow tip=stealth,
            additional arrow line width=1pt,
            additional item width=2cm
        }
    }
    \smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{
        Reward Function (R), Inverse Reinforcement Learning, Optimal Policy ($\pi$)
        }{below of module1/R that explains expert trajectories,above of module2/Environment Model (MDP), below of module3/Expert trajectories}
\end{figure}
```

This is the generated diagram-

[image]

I want to changes following things in this diagram-

1. The direction of arrow (From right to left and from top to bottom)
2. The look and feel of `additional` modules similar to other
3. The arrow corresponding to `additional` modules similar to other

Comment: Please always post compilable code as this makes it much easier to help and much more likely that a solution *will* help. You need at least a class, a `document` environment and the package for drawing the diagrams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing `arrow style` from the default `<-` to `->` ensures that the arrows go in the correct direction for the main nodes:

[image: reversed arrows]

For a uniform look to the arrows remove

```
additional arrow tip=stealth,
additional arrow line width=1pt,
```

[image: uniform arrows]

[I'm not sure if you want this or not.]

To support the arrows going in the different directions for the additional modules, you need to leave the automatic connections disabled and add them afterwards by hand.

```
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{module2/additional-module2}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{additional-module1/module1}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{module3/additional-module3}
```

To change the look of the additional modules, you can adapt their style using the keys described in the manual.

```
  additions={
    additional item offset=0.5cm,
    additional item border color=red,
    additional arrow color=red,
    additional item width=2cm,
    additional item height=2cm,
    additional item text width=3cm,
    additional item bottom color=red!50,
    additional item shadow=drop shadow,
  }
```

[image: manually added arrows in various directions]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{%
  back arrow disabled=true,
  module minimum width=2cm,
  module minimum height=2cm,
  module x sep=3cm,
  text width=2cm,
  arrow style=->,
  additions={
    additional item offset=0.5cm,
    additional item border color=red,
    additional arrow color=red,
    additional item width=2cm,
    additional item height=2cm,
    additional item text width=3cm,
    additional item bottom color=red!50,
    additional item shadow=drop shadow,
  }
}
\smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{
  Reward Function (R), Inverse Reinforcement Learning, Optimal Policy ($\pi$)
}{below of module1/R that explains expert trajectories,above of module2/Environment Model (MDP), below of module3/Expert trajectories}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{module2/additional-module2}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{additional-module1/module1}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{module3/additional-module3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I never use `smartdiagram` so I suggest a solution which instead use the pure TikZ picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shadows}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 9mm,
   MN/.style args = {#1/#2}{
            draw=#1,% line color
            top color=#2!10,
            bottom color=#2!80,
            rounded corners, thick,
            text width=27mm, minimum height=13mm, inner sep=1mm, 
            align=flush center},
      line/.style = {line width=2mm,
            draw=#1,%line color
            -{Triangle[length=2.8mm,width=4mm,fill=#1]},
            shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm
            },
        ds/.style = {drop shadow}
                    ]
%---
\linespread{0.9}
% bottom
\node (n1) [MN=red/white]                   {R that explains expert trajectories};
% middle
\node (n2) [MN=gray/red, ds,above=of n1]    {Reward Function (R)};
\node (n3) [MN=gray/cyan,ds,right=of n2]    {Inverse Reinforcement Learning};
\node (n4) [MN=gray/blue,ds,right=of n3]    {Optimal Policy ($\pi$)};
% bottom
\node (n5) [MN=red/white,below=of n4]       {Expert trajectories (R)};
% top
\node (n6) [MN=red/white,above=of n3]       {Environment Model (MDP)};
% lines
\draw[line=red]     (n6) edge (n3)
                    (n1) edge (n2)  (n5) to (n4);
\draw[line=cyan]    (n2) edge (n3);
\draw[line=blue]    (n3) edge (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I am big fan of `tikz`, I always prefer it. But recently I saw `smartdiagram`, and I thought of using it. I think `tikz` is the best option always. Thank you very much.